# Converting string date to date object and retriving time difference

Tags: string-manipulation, date-and-time

I am manipulating a text file, I need to extract dates from it, that will be in the format

XJan__28_,__2020X

where

_ is either 1 or zero whitespaces
__ is 1 or more than 1 whitespaces
X is a combination of 0 or more whitespaces and 0 or 1 newlines

I need to get the date and calculate the time difference (in days) from now to those dates. I would need a function timedifference[string_] that does that, but I don't know how to build it, (or better, I think I could do it in a very mechanical way, I hoped some expert could show me an easy and short solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for all of the specified combinations of whitespace/newline

```
date = "   Jan  28 ,  2020 \n"
dateObj = date // StringReplace[" " -> ""] // DateObject[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}] &
DateDifference[dateObj, Today]

(* Quantity[21, "Days"] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. DataObject is the function I needed

Comment: Does not work, "DateObject::str: String 
Jan28,2020 cannot be interpreted as a date."

Comment: What version are you running. Works fine on V12. https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ac3393d1-5728-4d45-837b-e537f114001e

Answer (score 2):

Since V 12.3 we have `FromDateString`:

```
date = "   Jan  28 ,  2020 \n";

dob = FromDateString @ date
```

[image]

```
DateDifference[dob, Today]
```

Quantity[1372, "Days"]